# Simple thermodynamic proof that light from a source cannot be focused to heat an object above the source's temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, optics

I was thinking about the question in the title.  I found the following thread, and some of the answers are making my head spin!

[Is it possible to focus the radiation from a black body to make something hotter than that black body?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/140949/is-it-possible-to-focus-the-radiation-from-a-black-body-to-make-something-hotter)

I am yet to delve into the world of optics (though I hope to soon) so I was hoping I could prove this proposition just using the laws of thermodynamics.  However, nobody in the thread above posted the proof that I came up with.

This takes the form of a proof by contradiction.  I construct a theoretical system in which the above process occurs, then analyse it to prove that it breaks the 2nd law of thermodynamics.  The system is as follows:

1. A light source with a temperature of 6000K (sufficiently large to be considered a thermal reservoir)
2. An object whose initial temperature is 1000K

Proposed Process:  The light from the source is focused onto the object.  The object is heated to a final temperature of 7000K.  For simplicity, assume no heat is transferred from the object to its surroundings during this process.

- Analysis:  The change in entropy of the hot reservoir is calculated
  by the following equation: $$\Delta S = -Q / T(\mathrm{Hot})$$ (Equation taken from
  [1], please advise me if I have not applied this correctly)
- The change in entropy of the object being heated is calculated with:
  $$\Delta S = m  C_p  \ln (T(\mathrm{Hot}) / T(\mathrm{Cold}))$$ (Equation taken from
  [2], please advise me if I have not applied this correctly)

Substituting the conditions of my system into the above equation with a value of 100 kJ for $Q$ and $C_p = 1\:\mathrm J / ( \mathrm{kg K} )$ and $m = 1\:\mathrm{kg}$ we get the following result:
\begin{align}
\Delta S (\mathrm{Total}) &= \Delta S (\mathrm{Hot Reservoir}) + \Delta S (\mathrm{Object}),
\\
\Delta S (\mathrm{Total}) &= - 100,000\:\mathrm{J} / 6000\:\mathrm{K} + \ln (7000\:\mathrm K / 1000\:\mathrm K) \times 1\:\mathrm J / ( \mathrm{kg K} ) \times 1\:\mathrm{kg}
\\
\Delta S (\mathrm{Total}) & = -14.7 \:\mathrm J /\mathrm K
\end{align}

The second law of thermodynamics states that the change in entropy for a real system must be greater than zero. Therefore, it is impossible to build a device that will focus the light from the source in such a way that it achieves the above.

Thus we have found a counterexample for this class of device, proving it cannot exist.

I realise that is a slightly different question to that in the other thread, as it was asking about the physical reasons why building such a device is not possible.  This required the use of the aforementioned head spinning optics!

Please would you advise me if you agree with my proof?

References

1. http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node41.html
2. http://www.chem.arizona.edu/~salzmanr/480a/480ants/2ndlawap/2ndlawap.html

Comment: Try the Clausius formulation of the second law: "Heat can never pass from a colder to a warmer body without some other change, connected therewith, occurring at the same time". That's all you need in one sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes this does disprove this concept in one sentence!  Not sure why I didn't think of this, it seems so obvious now..

Comment: Also I realise my example above also "proves" that an object cannot be heated to 5000 K..
Might have to give that some further thought!

Comment: Ah, it is because I just made up the final temperature.  When I actually calculate it using the first law (Q = mCPdeltaT) T(Final) = 101,000 K.  In this case the Delta S is positive.

However, if I use 7000 K as my final temperature, the Delta S is still very slightly positive.  Something is not quite right with my working..